# Should I use commas before and after the words "I feel" when expressing my opinion?

Tags: punctuation

Here's what I would like to write:

My professional experiences as a RN in inpatient acute care settings over 10 years and as an APNP have, I feel, provided me with many skills in the area of patient centered pain management in various settings.

Comment: The commas are perfectly apposite in that example. But I wouldn't enshrine it as a rule that *I feel* is always parenthetical. *I feel she knows what she is talking about when she says that*.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I would rewrite the sentence. If this is a written job interview or personal statement, then exclude "I feel" altogether. Also, if you intend your reader to read as AHR-EN, then use the article AN rather than A. In your example "patient-centered pain" (hyphenate a compound adjective preceding a noun). Write numbers in roman text rather than arabic numerals for numbers up to one hundred in formal prose (there's some variability from style guide to style guide, but "10" will always be written as "ten." Acute care is always inpatient; I'd exclude it. Ninety-nine point nine percent of people don't know that APNP stands for Advanced Practice Nurse Practitioner--especially any recruiter outside of the West Coast.

Here goes:
I have a great deal of experience with patient-centered pain management. For ten years, I worked in acute care, where immediate relief of pain was an obvious necessity often leading to long-term management. As an advanced practice nurse, I am also well-versed in the risks of abuse and diversion.

Comment: It is ok (CHICAGO MANUAL OF STYLE) to use numerals for percentages if they don't start a sentence. "I imagine 99.9% of people don't know ..."